# Connecting different number USB pins

Tags: usb

Can I connect my 4 pin 2.0 USB to the 10 pin 2.0 connector on the motherboard? Also on the motherboard connectors say +5v,p12-,p14+, GND. That is the the four pin side  of the ten pin connector.

[image]

Comment: The answer is yes, you can. You'll need to make sure to connect it to the correct side. Matching the labels of the pins should help. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, the red wire normally goes towards the left of the connector. VCC-> +5v

Answer (score 2):

Here is the standard pinout of a USB 2.0 mainboard connector:

[image]

Your cables have all colors matched.